# Confused about an object's dimensions

Tags: modeling

[image]

Hi.

I'm having such a hard time trying to fathom the dimensions of this object I just imported:

x 54.6m
y 169m
z 79.8m

It would seem to me that the height(z-axis) would be 3-5 times greater than the width or the length( x- or y-axis).

thx

Comment: Different editing programs have different "up" axis - your object could be "confused" as to it's orientation. With your object selected, press Ctrl+A, select "rotation" and see if that fixes it.

Answer (score 9):

From the properties panel to the right of the viewport in your screenshot, the mesh is rotated 90 degrees around the X axis. The dimensions are shown as local to the object, so what you’re seeing in the scene is the object after the rotation. Rotating around X will effectively swap the Y and Z dimensions - so ‘Y’ is the height of the figure.